# my php code send empty email

Tags: php, email

Please, this is php code that i used to send from HTML contact page, it works with out error but only i receive empty email! just the object of email i get and nothing else.

```
 <?php

$email_address = $_POST["email"];
$tel_num = $_POST["tel"];
$first_name = $_POST["f_name"];
$last_name = $_POST["l_name"];
$text_send = $_POST["email_text"];
$to_com = "myemal@gmail.com" ;
$subject = " New eMail" ;

    mail ($to_com, $subject, $text_send, " From: " . $email_address . $tel_num . $first_name .$last_name );

    echo "Your Massage has been sent" ;

?>
```

So please i need some help?

Comment: Please share your html code as well

Comment: Your 'headers' argument is messed up. Review the documentation again.

Comment: Above and where you php is located

Comment: var_dump($_POST) to get all the variables that are coming from form submit, check if the email_text is coming as well!!

Comment: 1- I put the php file with website files on server.

Comment: 2. I uesd var_dump($_POST) but shows Null with message of your email has been sent and also empty email .

Comment: 3. This is the HTML code that i am using <form action='mycontact.php' mathod='post' name='contactform'> <input type="email" name="email" id="email"> <input name="tel" type="tel" id="tel"> <input type="text" name="f_name" id="Adi"> <input type="text" name="l_name" id="Suyad"> <textarea name="email_text" cols="80" rows="10" maxlength="250" autofocus wrap="soft" id="email text" title="Write Here"></textarea> <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" title="Send" value="Submit"> </form>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at this example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

the line endings in the header (`\r\n`) are very important

Comment: This is the HTML code that i am using
   
   <form action='mycontact.php' mathod='post' name='contactform'>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
 
   <input name="tel" type="tel" id="tel">
 
      <input type="text" name="f_name" id="Adi">
 
      <input type="text" name="l_name" id="Suyad">
 
   <textarea name="email_text" cols="80" rows="10" maxlength="250" autofocus wrap="soft" id="email text" title="Write Here"></textarea>
 
   <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" title="Send" value="Submit">
 
 </form>

Comment: Please the code that you sent, it is working as well but when i use my textbox input nothing i get same problem? i have changed the input text from HTML same problem!

Comment: typo in ur form definition: `mathod` needs to be `method`.